# Is there any way to find out how many http connections are open while browsing a web page

Tags: netstat, httpconnection

Like when I access yahoo email , I see yahoo downloads contents from various other servers , like ad.yieldmanager.com , img.yahoo.com ,etc ,when I am in a web page how do I find out all the http connections it has opened to load the web page ?

Answer (score 0):

Use firefox and get [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).  Then use the net console to [monitor](http://getfirebug.com/network).

Answer (score 0):

**Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).**

**It's good.**